# My prefix you can find in every potion, my suffix is between a place and motion

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> My prefix you can find in every potion
>   My suffix is between a place and motion
>   My infix may push you to pick up a girl
>   And fools believe my whole can store a soul

English is not my native language, so any remarks will be appreciated.

Comment: *between a place and motion* I'm have no idea what this could mean, but I'm also not a native English speaker, so...

Comment: [Gustavo Gabriel](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/44445/gustavo-gabriel) - well, it means what it means, it's a riddle anyway)) My only fear is that I may mislead people with wrong articles.




So, if someone thinks that he got the answer if some articles in the question can be changed - give it a try.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Knowing of some [Native American and Australian Aboriginal beliefs](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/8380/did-some-cultures-believe-that-photography-can-steal-your-soul) that mirrors or cameras can [steal their souls](https://www.csicop.org/sb/show/soul_theft_through_photography), I tried to fit them into the clues.
>
>  While those don't seem to work, a `Photo` would!
>
>  "pH" is a property of every potion and "hot" would work for the infix, but the suffix is...more creative.
>  When we say "drive to town", the "to" is between a place(town) and a motion(drive).

Comment: Great! Almost solved. Your second suffix variant is correct, but verb selection is wider - we can rot13(tb gb cnex) or rot13(geniry gb Rtlcg).
Find the correct prefix and I will mark your answer.

Comment: You didn't explain the infix ...

Answer (score 1):

> My prefix is in every 'P'otion: (the letter 'P')
>  My suffix is between place and motion: the letter 'd', common abbreviation for distance.
>  My infix may push you to pick up a girl: your 'Posse'.
>  Fools believe my whole can store a soul:
>  Answer: 'Possessed'

Comment: Nice! But the reason that push you to pick up the girl may be her "pose". And "posse", as Google say, is a squad of men raised by sheriff to help him. So, not this one.

Comment: @ErikGecas Hello and welcome to the PSE. Please hide your answers in spoilers.

Answer (score 0):

Attempt:

> necromancer - someone who is able to store a soul

Reason:

> Infix: romance - causes you to try to pick up a girl. (This is my main reason for trying this answer)
>  Prefix: Nec(tar) is a kind of potion including "nec"
>  Suffix: "r" is between "Promenade" (a place) and "Promenader" (motion).

Comment: Nice try! I like that combination. Rot13(Naq rira zber - cersvk bs lbhe nafjre pbhyq or rnfvyl punatrq, jvgu gur punatr bs gur ryrzrag.) So it's probably possible to find a suitable prefix. But i can't see a suitable suffix anyway.